# Trying to develop a code in Jupyter-python, that allows me to scrape the first table from any wikipedia page but going wrong somewhere! Code attached

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping, jupyter-notebook

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

wiki = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dogs_in_the_United_States')

soup = BeautifulSoup(wiki.content, 'html.parser')

# Get all the tables
tables = soup.find_all(class_='wikitable sortable')

extract_table = tables[0]

# extract the column names
for item in extract_table:
    column_finder = item.find_all('th')
    colmn_names = column_finder.contents(0)
    specific_row = item.find_all('td')
    name_row = specific_row.contents(0)

#put all the content into a list
values=[]

for new in extract_table:
    for item in new.select('td'):
        vari = item.get_text()
        values.append(vari)

import pandas as pd

#create data frame 

df = pd.DataFrame(values, columns=headers)

#show df
df

#write df to csv file
df.to_csv("df_1sttable.csv", index=False)

df
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit your question to state specifically what is wrong, sharing the error message if there is one.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

The iteration section can be improved as below.

```
extract_table = tables[0]

#extract all the table rows
rows = extract_table.find_all('tr')

#get header information from the first element
headers = rows[0].find_all('th') 
headers = [th.text.strip() for th in headers]

#get data points from the table
values = []
for row in rows[1:]:
    data = row.find_all('td')
    data = [td.text.strip() for td in data]
    values.append([ele for ele in data if ele])

df = pd.DataFrame(values, columns=headers)
```

You can also try pandas.read_html() method which reads HTML tables into a list of DataFrame objects.

```
1. df = pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dogs_in_the_United_States')[0]

2. df = pd.read_html(str(extract_table))[0]
```

And, the final step is,

```
df.to_csv("df_1sttable.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! This was very helpful

Comment: Glad, it helped. You can accept the answer if you like.